# Font size inconsistencies on safari

Tags: html, css, safari

my font size is fine on chrome and firefox. When viewed on safari, things go downhill completely. The font size is ginormous.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZEdXZ

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-sm-height">
            <section class="col-sm-6">
                <a href='@Url.Action("Top6GolfTerms", "Golf")'>

                </a>
            </section>
            <aside class="col-sm-6">
                <div>
                    <span> <a id="Article_Category">Golf</a></span>
                    <h2 id="Article_Header2">
                      <a id="Article_Title">
                     UFC Champions: The 5 Most Influential Fighters That Will Go Down Into UFC History
                      </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
   <hr>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row-sm-height">
            <section class="col-sm-6">
                <a href='@Url.Action("MostInfluentialUfcFIghters", "MMA")'>

                 </a>
            </section>
            <aside class="col-sm-6">
                <div>
                     <span> <a id="Article_Category">UFC</a></span>
                     <h2 id="Article_Header2">
                      <a id="Article_Title">
                     UFC Champions: The 5 Most Influential Fighters That Will Go Down Into UFC History
                      </p>

                    </h2>
                </div>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</section>
```

I've tried multiple things such as changing text size to % instead of using px. I tried using `text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;`

On Chrome http://snag.gy/K7BjL.jpg
On Safari http://snag.gy/kOXad.jpg

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing from those screenshots the problem you are having is that fonts change. AFAIK not all fonts are the same size even if set to the same size. Try a different font family.